# Converting an IObservable to SourceCache with Dynamic Data

Tags: xamarin, dynamic-data, reactiveui

I'm new to ReactiveUI and I'm trying to add bits of it to my Xamarin Forms application. We have a service method that returns an IObservable.

```
IObservable<List<DiningArea>> diningAreaObservable = _tableService.GetAllDiningAreas();
```

This works and previously we've subscribed to this and mapped the results into an ObservableCollection. I'd like to replace this and start using Dynamic Data. So I've setup some global's with the XAML collection view's binding source being DiningAreas.

```
private SourceCache<DiningArea, int> _diningAreas = new SourceCache<DiningArea, int>(x => x.Id);
private ReadOnlyObservableCollection<DiningArea> _diningAreaCollection;

public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<DiningArea> DiningAreas => _diningAreaCollection;
```

Now in my ViewModel I call the service, get back an observable but how do I add the observable to the SourceCache. I can see how to convert it to an IChangeSet but I want it to be apart of _diningAreas.

```
IObservable<List<DiningArea>> diningAreaObservable = _tableService.GetAllDiningAreas();

IObservable<IChangeSet<DiningArea, int>> diningAreaChangeSet = diningAreaObservable.ToObservableChangeSet(t => t.Id);

_diningAreas.AddOrUpdate(new DiningArea { Id = 0, Name = "All", Position = 0 });

var diningAreaDisposable = _diningAreas.Connect()
  .Sort(SortExpressionComparer<DiningArea>.Ascending(z => z.Position))
  .Bind(out _diningAreaCollection)
  .Subscribe();
```

Am I understanding this correctly or am I doing something backwards?

Comment: Do you need the sourcecache? You can just do Connect from your `diningAreaChangeSet` and bind to your read-only observable collection.

Comment: And you can even do `StartsWith` to get your all entry on your first observable.